# Survey Error "Oops. It looks like there is no response option configured."

Tags: civicampaign

I have created a campaign and now created my first survey. I added the questions I want answered and then reserved some respondents. When I click on interview respondents, I get the error message "Oops. It looks like there is no response option configured."

What am I missing or what have I done wrong please?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to mention your CiviCRM version?  Are you able to replicate this problem at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you make if you have added the options or selected existing options under Results tab of a Survey settings?

[image]

Comment: Yep, that was it. Couldn't see that anywhere in the documentation. Thanks so much. Absolute lifesaver.